# Uploading video using Vimeo Tus Protocol from Mobile (Ionic-cordova)

Tags: cordova, ionic3, vimeo

Problem:While Uploading a video to vimeo account from mobile(ionic-cordova) using tus protocol it is upload only 15 bytes weather uploading from browser it uploads perfectly.

We are creating a Ionic -Cordova app which uploading a video to vimeo account using the tus-js-client protocol (https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/tus-js-client).

For browser it is working fine but in mobile it upload 15 bytes continue sly which is very slow.

We used a cordova capture plugin to take a video and cordova file plugin to get a fileobject and then pass that object to tus-js-client library but not working properly

Please provide me a way to solve it.

We first call to our back-end API which create a video file to vimeo account and return the vimeo response on that we use upload_link url from the response and then upload it using below code.

Please provide a way to solve it.

Example:

```
let upload = new tus.Upload(vimeoObj.file, {
    endpoint: 'none',
    retryDelays: [0, 1000, 3000, 5000],
    uploadSize: vimeoObj.params.filesize,
    onError: (error) => {
        // error
    },
    onProgress: (bytesUploaded, bytesTotal) => {
        // progress
    },
    onSuccess: () => {
        // sucess
    }
})
upload.url = response['data']['body']['upload']['upload_link']
upload.start()
```

Answer (score 0):

Kind of late to answer but tus-js-client sends a file in a chunks. In Cordova's FileReader recursive next slice function call should be called when reading slice is succeed in registered onload or onloadend event handlers. tus-js-client has now PR https://github.com/tus/tus-js-client/pull/134 where that is implemented and hopefully soon it supports cordova also.